# c# read DataSet Child tables

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-2.0

```
  <products>
    <product id="1">
          <photos>
            <photo addr="1.jpg" />
          </photos>
          <parameters>
            <parameter name="name" />
          </parameters>
    </product>
  </products>
```

Hello, I have this xml, I want to get values, like photo addr or parameter name I can't.
 in DataGrid I am getting like new table. How to Read this parameters by product id?

```
        foreach (DataTable t in dataSet.Tables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t);
        }
```

I am getting: product, photos, photo, parameters, parameter.

Sorry for my English

Comment: This portion of you question: "when I am trying to get values from DataSet it gives all namespaces give new tables." does not make much sense.  Could you clear that up?

Comment: I'd start with what you really want to do in the end, load/save xml in datasets are more for saving data off once it is in the dataset and then load the data back from that xml file written by the dataset object.

Comment: I would suggest looking into [XmlSerialization](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm). Or, you could use LINQ to XML. Or you could use a simple XmlReader with XPaths? All of these solutions can work at reading XML into C#, but it depends on what best fits your project.

Answer (score 0):

By default DataSet assumes a schema based on elements, not attributes. You'd need to build an xsd for your data to get DataSet to read that XML correctly.

Due to the way this XML is constructed there's no easy way to read this into a DataSet directly. You'd have to use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to generate an xsd file and then hand edit it with appropriate attributes from the msdata namespace. It's a quite painful process.

You coud transform the document to a form which would probably parse correctly into DataSet either by rewriting the XML using LINQ or applying an [XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx):

```
<products>
     <product id="1">
         <photo addr="1.jpg" />
         <parameter name="name" />
     </product>
</products>
```

You could also consider using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) on it instead of trying to use a DataSet:

```
var productsInfo = from product in productsElement.Descendants("product")
                   from photo in product.Descendants("photo")
                   from parameter in product.Descendants("parameter")
                   let id = product.Attribute("id")
                   let addr = photo.Attribute("addr")
                   let name = parameter.Attribute("name")
                   select new { ID = id.Value, Addr = addr.Value, Name = name.Value};
```

If you're developing a new XML layout rather than working with an existing one, you can create the DataSet first using the designer. Populate it with some dummy data, then you can use [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135425.aspx) to get the xsd schema and sample data. To preserve relationshps in the XML ouput be sure to set the Nested property on your Relations to be true (See [Nesting DataRelations (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfkwf9s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

OK, you need to use schema inferencing to generate an XSD file, then run xsd.exe to generate the DataSet that you're looking for.

To begin with, the XML you've provided won't work off the bat, because you don't have a root node. I'm taking a wild guess here, but if `<products>` is the root node, we could reformat your XML to look like this:

```
<products>
  <product id="1">
    <photos>
      <photo addr="1.jpg" />
    </photos>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="name1" />
    </parameters>
  </product>
  <product id="2">
    <photos>
      <photo addr="2.jpg" />
    </photos>
    <parameters>
      <parameter name="name2" />
    </parameters>
  </product>
</products>
```

We could then take this XML and infer the XSD from it via the `XmlSchemaInference` class. When I inferred the schema from the XML above, I got this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="products">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="product">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="photos">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="photo">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="addr" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="parameters">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="parameter">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I then ran `xsd.exe` with the /dataset option, which gave me a fully functional `DataSet` representing the original XML. Populating the dataset and the using the `DataSet.GetXml()` returns the expected XML result.

Final note: I'm not advocating the use of DataSets over domain objects, etc etc. I just wanted to show you what would be the steps for accomplishing your stated objective.